# Python ошибка list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

Tags: python

Необходимо пройтись по списку robots и сравнить словари со значением с new_version, если версия ниже чем new_version - вернуть в виде:

Ошибка:

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

Код проверки:

```
robots = [
  { "core_version": 9 },
  { "core_version": 13 },
  { "core_version": 16 },
  { "core_version": 9 },
  { "core_version": 14 },
]

get_outdated(robots, 10) == [0, 3]
```

Мой код:

```
def get_outdated(robots: list, new_version: int) -> list:
    for i in range robots:
        if robots[i] < new_version:
            return robots["core_version"]
```

Comment: я так понимаю основная проблема с ошибками чаще всего в том что лень перевести с английского.

Comment: print(i) сделайте и посмотрите.

Comment: @SergeyTatarintsev, Не там другая проблема, посерьезней. Там нежелание читать учебники. (там один большой ПОХРЕН на все, включая синтаксис языка)

Comment: Поместить 4 словаря в список было гениальным решением

Comment: Умники, я только учусь, и это тесты с моих курсов, я могу использовать готовое решение, но обратился сюда за объяснением ошибок

Comment: Для начала посмотрите в документации синтаксис функции `range`. У вас в этом коде вообще другая ошибка должна быть, вы его запускали? Да и не нужен тут `range`, я бы лучше сделал перебор `for data in robots:` и дальше проверка `data["core_version"]`

Comment: последний код не работает. он возвращает 9. а надо [0, 3]

Answer (score 0):

У вас в последней строке функции вы обращаетесь к списку `robots`. В списке индексы - это числа(ну либо срез). В словарях вы в качестве некого индекса используются ключи, которые могут быть строками. У вас robots - это список словарей. Т.е. для начала вы должны достать словарь из списка, а затем взять нужное значение по ключу. Так же есть аналогичная ошибка в ифе и неправильно задан range в форе.

```
def get_outdated(robots: list, new_version: int) -> list:
    for i in range(len(robots)):
        if robots[i]["core_version"] < new_version:
            return robots[i]["core_version"]
```

Вроде все ошибки исправил, если ещё что-то то пишите, будем разбираться.

Comment: Поскольку тут `i` используется только для доступа к `robots[i]`, то проще уж сразу перебирать элементы списка `robots`, а не его индексы.

Comment: Да, просто хотелось как меньше изменений вносить в код

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range robots
```

не будет работать по синтаксису.
Надо или

```
for i in range(len(robots))
```

или

```
for d in robots
```

Answer (score 0):

Дальше у вас:

```
if robots[i] < new_version:
```

Получается, вы сравниваете целое (int) со словарём. А надо  - со значением в словаре.

```
if robots[i]["core_version"] < new_version:
```

Ну и возвращаете вы не корректно. Правильно:

```
return robots[i]["core_version"]
```

Итого:

```
robots = [
  {"core_version": 9},
  {"core_version": 13},
  {"core_version": 16},
  {"core_version": 9},
  {"core_version": 14},
]

def get_outdated(robots: list, new_version: int) -> list:
    for i in range(len(robots)):
        if robots[i]["core_version"] < new_version:
            return robots[i]["core_version"]

get_outdated(robots, 10) == [0, 3]
```

Теперь вопрос. Вы пишите, что нужно пройтись по списку. Но функция не проходится по списку, а возвращает ответ только для первого элемента.
Уточните, в каком виде необходим ответ?

Comment: Объедините ответы в один, вы же можете редактировать ответ